# Passing Python list of objects and receiving as C++ base class vector not working

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm struggling to get this to work:

```
// C++ Code
class Base {
public:
    Base();
};
class Poly1: public Base {
public:
    int polymethod() { return 5; }
};
class Poly2: public Base {
public:
    int polymethod() { return 6; }
};

class Processor {
public:
   void process(std::vector<Base*> v) {};
   void process(Base* p) {}
};

// Py bindings C++ code
// skipping a bunch of PyBind11 details
class PyProcessor {
cls

.def("processAll", [](Processor& p, std::vector<Base*> v) {  p.process(v) }, PY_RVP_REFERENCE, PY_HELP("Do something"))

.def("process", [](Processor& p, Base* v) { p.process(v) }, PY_RVP_REFERENCE, PY_HELP("Do something"));
}
```

Binding are all in place for these classes so imagine I have a Python list like this:

processor = createProcessor()

```
p1 = createPoly1() # createPoly1 returns a Poly1 object
p2 = createPoly2() # createPoly2 returns a Poly2 object
```

I call these functions just fine:

```
processor.process(p1)
processor.process(p2)
```

But if I put these into a list and call ProcessAll

```
l = [p1]
processor.processAll(l)
```

I get a type error:

```
TypeError: processAll(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: Processor, arg0: List[Base]) -> None
    2. (self: Processor, arg0: List[Base]) -> None
Invoked with: <Processor object at 0x000001E7D9F3AEF0>, {<Poly1 object at 0x000001E7D9F39030>}
```

**QUESTION:** This suggests that the bindings for STL containers like `std::vector` can't support polymorphism like passing in a single object (e.g. processor.process(p1) does.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: For a start, `polymethod()` is not polymorphic. Baseclass destructor should be `virtual` or `protected`. Smart pointers can be used as well. Also, this really needs a [mcve] before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason behind the error that you have is that you have forgotten to include pybind11 header specific to support C++ containers, that is `<pybind11/stl.h>`. But if I bind your classes like this and include this header file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h> // do not forget this one


namespace py = pybind11;


void ExposePointereCollection(pybind11::module_& py_module)
{
   py::class_<Base>(py_module, "Base")
      .def(py::init<>());

   py::class_<Poly1, Base>(py_module, "Poly1")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("polymethod", &Poly1::polymethod);

   py::class_<Poly2, Base>(py_module, "Poly2")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("polymethod", &Poly2::polymethod);;


   py::class_<Processor>(py_module, "PyProcessor")
      .def(py::init<>())      
      .def("processAll", [](Processor& p, std::vector<Base*> v) 
         { 
            p.process(v); 
            return "Process with a vector is called. ";
         }
      )
      .def("process", [](Processor& p, Base* v) 
         {
            p.process(v);  
            return "Process with a pointer is called. ";
         })
      ;
}
```

Now, if I write a simple python script like this:
from Py_cpp_lib import Base, Poly1, Poly2, PyProcessor

```
p1 = Poly1();
p2 = Poly2();

proc = PyProcessor();

print(proc.process(p1));
print(proc.process(p2));

l = [p1, p2]
print(proc.processAll(l));
```

You will have the correct result:

```
$ python test.py
Process with a pointer is called.
Process with a pointer is called.
Process with a vector is called.
```

---

**Note:** If I remove the mentioned include file (i.e. `<pybind11\stl.h>`), the program still compiles fine, but I get the following error during the run of script:

```
$ python test.py
Process with a pointer is called.
Process with a pointer is called.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(proc.processAll(l));
TypeError: processAll(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: Py_cpp_lib.PyProcessor, arg0: std::vector<Base * __ptr64,std::allocator<Base * __ptr64> >) -> str

Invoked with: <Py_cpp_lib.PyProcessor object at 0x00000213213FB730>, [<Py_cpp_lib.Poly1 object at 0x0000021321404970>, <Py_cpp_lib.Poly2 object at 0x0000021321407830>]
```